# MySQL: Replace null with 0 in GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-concat, sqlfiddle

I have a table called `trx`

```
trx_year  trx_month  Product  number_of_trx 
2018      4          A        100
2018      5          A        300
2018      3          A        500
2018      1          A        200
2018      2          A        150
2018      5          B        400
2018      2          B        200
2018      1          B        350
```

> I want the result:
>
> Product with the number of trx that order by month asc

I have a query like this:

```
select product,GROUP_CONCAT(number_of_trx order by trx_month)
from trx
where trx_year=2018
group by product
```

The Result of that query:

```
Product  Data
A     200,150,500,100,300
B     350,200,400
```

But, I want Result like this: (that the null value of the month replaced by 0)

```
Product  Data
A     200,150,500,100,300
B     350,200,0,0,400
```

I already try `ifnull()` and `coalesce()` like this: (but the result is same as before)

```
select product,GROUP_CONCAT(ifnull(number_of_trx,0) order by trx_month)
from trx
where trx_year=2018
group by product;

select product,GROUP_CONCAT(coalesce(number_of_trx,0) order by trx_month)
from trx
where trx_year=2018
group by product;
```

maybe you can help me, please check http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f1ed4/3

Comment: why 0,0 in the middle ? is there any rule?

Comment: There are no null values in your data set

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin becaus the max month is 5(may), and product B didn't have trx in month 3 & 4

Comment: @Strawberry There are null value in Product B, It doesn't have transaction in month 3 & 4

Comment: That's not quite the same thing....

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f1ed4/44

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up with. Probably could be more efficient but you can get ideas from it. Join to product table instead of selecting distinct products. Also expand to include months beyond 5.

```
SELECT trx2.product, GROUP_CONCAT(trx2.total order by trx2.trx_month)
FROM
(SELECT temp2.product, temp2.trx_month, SUM(temp2.number_of_trx) AS total
FROM
(SELECT products.product, temp1.trx_month, temp1.number_of_trx
FROM (select 1 as trx_month, 0 as number_of_trx
UNION select 2, 0
UNION select 3, 0
UNION select 4, 0
UNION select 5, 0) as temp1,
(SELECT distinct product from trx) AS products

UNION ALL

SELECT trx.product, trx.trx_month, trx.number_of_trx
FROM trx) as temp2
GROUP BY temp2.product, temp2.trx_month) AS trx2
GROUP BY product
```

Comment: Updated my response and tested it with your fiddle.

Comment: I found the answer by editing your query. [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2c9bbd/10](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2c9bbd/10). Thank you for the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Generate all the rows you want using `cross join`.  That would be all product/month combinations.  Then use `left join` to bring in data and `group by` to condense it:

```
select p.product,
       group_concat(coalesce(trx.number_of_trx, 0) order by trx_month)
from (select distinct product from trx) p cross join
     (select distinct trx_year, trx_month
      from trx
      where trx_year = 2018
     ) yyyymm left join
     trx
     on trx.product = p.product and
        trx.trx_year = yyyymm.trx_year
        trx.trx_month = yyyymm.trx_month
group by p.product
```

Note the `order by` in the `group_concat()`.  This is very important if you want the results in chronological order.

Answer (score 0):

Group by groups the table contents with available values.
FOR Product A: months 1 2 3 4 5 are available and 
FOR Product B: months 1 2 5 are available

It will not fill table automatically with month 3 and 4 against product B

To resolve this
Either you will have to fill this table with B - 3 and B - 4 and 0 value for number of trx
OR you can create temp table and do the same in that.

To implement this, 
1. you will have to use date function (convert your month and year value to date) 
2. Increase month value for each loop, If the month value is not available against current product value, insert record in the table.
3. Then run your group by query on this updated table and it will give you required result.

This is bit complicated task to implement. You will have to do multiple checks.

If I will find any other solution, I will post. Thanks.

Comment: Another method: 
You can create another table that contains Product and month value, so 12 rows for each product and join that table with trx.

Comment: What you guys think of my response?

Comment: can you try your idea in my [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f1ed4/3) ? @HardikNuwal

Answer (score 0):

select product,GROUP_CONCAT(number_of_trx) order by trx_month),
group_concat(case when  trx_year = 2018 then number_of_trx else 0 end)as data
from trx
group by product;

Answer (score 0):

**If concat is null then returns 0 else returns values**

> SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 10000000;
> SELECT coalesce(group_concat(DISTINCT columnname),0) as values