# How to replace null with 0 in GROUP_CONCAT?

Tags: sqlite, group-by, window-functions, group-concat, coalesce

I couldn't apply [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51435035/mysql-replace-null-with-0-in-group-concat) as my database structure is different.

My appointment table has dates in yyyy-mm-dd format and status of appointments as pending, cancelled and completed. My query generates comma separated results for 12 months :

```
$pending = $con->query("SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(cnt) cnt
FROM (select count(*) cnt from appointment where strftime('%Y', date) = '2022' and status like '%PENDING%' GROUP BY strftime('%m', date)) q;")->fetchColumn();
```

There are no dates for some months, I want 0 in those result sets. All months except February and April have 1 appointment and I would like the result to be like
1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1.

I tried this but it didn't help :

```
$pending = $con->query("SELECT coalesce(GROUP_CONCAT(cnt),0) cnt
    FROM (select count(*) cnt from appointment where strftime('%Y', date) = '2022' and status like '%PENDING%' GROUP BY strftime('%m', date)) q;")->fetchColumn();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a CTE that returns all the month numbers `01` to `12` and do a `LEFT` join to the table:

```
WITH months(month) AS (VALUES ('01'), ('02'), ('03'), ('04'), ('05'), ('06'), ('07'), ('08'), ('09'), ('10'), ('11'), ('12'))
SELECT DISTINCT GROUP_CONCAT(COUNT(a.date)) OVER (
                  ORDER BY m.month 
                  ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
                ) result 
FROM months m LEFT JOIN appointment a
ON strftime('%m', a.date) = m.month AND strftime('%Y', a.date) = '2022' AND a.status LIKE '%PENDING%' 
GROUP BY m.month;
```

Instead of `GROUP_CONCAT()` aggregate function, which does not support an `ORDER BY` clause, I use `GROUP_CONCAT()` window function.

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=dbc2eac43dd3499957c867a426124d06).

Comment: You sir are a lifesaver :) Thank you very much , it solved the issue. I had a follow up question for the same query. If instead of where strftime('%Y', date) = '2022' "year" I have date range from date and two date like where date between '2022-01-01' and '2022-05-01' how can i modify the query for the same ?

Comment: @Abey instead of `strftime('%Y', a.date) = '2022'` use `a.date BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-05-01'`